# Prevent Wordpress settings save - validation

Tags: php, validation, wordpress

**My function for validation:**

```
 function my_plg_validate_options( $input ) {

  $valid = array();

  if ( is_numeric( $input['num_tags'] ) )
        $valid['num_tags'] = $input['num_tags'];
  else
        add_settings_error('my_plg_validate_num_tags_field','my_plg_validate_num_tags_error','Incorrect value entered!','error');


  if(!empty($valid))
  {
    return $valid;
  }

}
```

***EDIT***

```
function my_plg_options_page()
{
  ?>
  <div class='wrap'>
   <h2>Tagara | Postavke </h2>

   <form action="options.php" method="post">

     <?php settings_fields('my_plg_options'); ?>
     <?php do_settings_sections('my_plg'); ?>
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button button-primary" />
   </form>
  </div>


}


function nd_tch_tagara_admin_init(){
  register_setting( 'my_plg_options', 'my_plg_options','my_plg_validate_options' );

  add_settings_section( 'my_plg_main', 'Postavke plugina','my_plg_section_text', 'my_plg' );
  add_settings_field( 'my_plg_num_tags_field', 'Unesite broj tagova','my_plg_setting_input', 'my_plg', 'my_plg_main' );
}
```

It saves, well nothing and overrides my previous value (*Field in database is empty)* if num_tags is not a number. How to prevent Wordpress to  override previous value saved in setting if validation don't pass.

Comment: When and how does this function get called? How does the function that saves the setting look like? It would be helpful to see the function that does the actual saving of the settings, because this validation code does not seem to touch the database or save any settings.

Comment: I have posted some update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you code will look like:

```
function my_plg_validate_options( $input ) {
    $old_option = get_option('name_option'); // Your option name
    if ( ! is_numeric( $input['num_tags'] ) ) {
        $input['num_tags'] = $old_option['num_tags'];
        add_settings_error('my_plg_validate_num_tags_field','my_plg_validate_num_tags_error','Incorrect value entered!','error');
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Replace name_option with your. Hope that help!

Updated:

In your case:

```
function my_plg_validate_options( $input ) {
    $option_name = 'my_plg_options';
    $old_option = get_option($option_name); // Your option name
    if ( ! is_numeric( $input['num_tags'] ) ) {
        $input['num_tags'] = $old_option['num_tags'];
        add_settings_error('my_plg_validate_num_tags_field','my_plg_validate_num_tags_error','Incorrect value entered!','error');
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's working for me. I have tailored your anwser fully for my needs. Simple and good solution. But why have I think that reassignment will be done automaticaly ?  I belive in magic :P

Comment: Yes, You are right if this is a main function for saving, but it is not.  my_plg_validate_options is a sanitize callback function so it's mission will be validate data and that's it.